# How to use PHP in combination with the IIS7?

Tags: windows, iis, php, web-server, isapi

I have enabled IIS7 and would like to use it in combination with PHP. For that I have already installed PHP. And than I found a [rather detailed description](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/09/19/How-to-install-PHP-on-IIS7-_2800_RC1_2900_.aspx) of how I can make IIS7 be able to use PHP. However, I have problems on the very last steps. As executable I need to indicate "php5isapi.dll" and I do not have this file. In my "C:\Program Files\PHP" I have several *.dll files: libeay32.dll, libpq.dll, php5ts.dll, ssleay32.dll. I tried to use "php5ts.dll" (because it's name is the most similar to the "php5isapi.dll").

When I press OK I get a window which is very similar to those given in the instruction. It is written there:

> Do you want to allow this ISAPI
> extension? Click "Yes" and add the
> extension with an "Allowed" entry to
> the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions list or
> to update an existing extension entry
> to "Allowed" in the ISAPI and CGI
> Restriction list.

I click "Yes" and get an window with an error message:

> The specified module required by this
> handler is not in the modules list. If
> you are adding a script map handler
> mapping, the IsapiModule or the
> CgiModule must be in the modules list.

Can anybody explain me what's going on here?

Comment: If you used the PHP installer I would definitely recommend going back and grabbing the binaries yourself. I had lots of problems when I went to install PHP last, the installer does not contain all the files found in the direct binary download and for using with iis7 I found that I in fact needed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question over on SO:

[**Why is php5isapi.dll missing after installing PHP for Windows?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235437/why-is-php5isapi-dll-missing-after-installing-php-for-windows)